# How to read a value in dockerfile during run-time

Tags: docker, devops

I am having a use-case in which i am storing two arguments in openshift config map as below -

```
DT_URL="https://www.something.com"
DT_TOKEN="1234ABCD"
```

Now i want these values to be fetched during run-time using jenkins. In my dockerfile i have arguments as below-

```
ARG URL=${DT_URL}
ARG TOKEN=${DT_TOKEN}
```

Unfortunately i am not getting any values fetched. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARG` is used to define variables that live only during the image build-time.
`ENV` can be used to define environment variables that live during image build-time and container run-time.

The problem here is that you can only pass `ARGs`, when you build the image, using the `--build-arg` option.

However, nothing is stopping you to assign the value of an `ARG` to an `ENV`, inside the Dockerfile.
Here is a example:

**Create a `Dockerfile`**

```
FROM alpine
ARG MY_ARG
ENV MY_ENV=$MY_ARG
RUN echo "the env is:" $MY_ENV
RUN echo "the arg is:" $MY_ARG
```

**Build the image:**

```
docker build -t arg-env-example --build-arg MY_ARG=some_value .
```

Both the ARG and the ENV were assigned *some_value* during build time:

```
...
Step 4/5 : RUN echo "the env is:" $MY_ENV
 ---> Running in 9a383134c927
the env is: some_value
Removing intermediate container 9a383134c927
 ---> 8a2d83609296
Step 5/5 : RUN echo "the arg is:" $MY_ARG
 ---> Running in b881d9f4208e
the arg is: some_value
...
```

**Run the container and check both the `ARG` and the `ENV`:**

```
docker run -it arg-env-example sh

/ # echo $MY_ENV
some_value   << this is the value that was passed at build-time to MY_ARG
/ # echo $MY_ARG
      << nothing here :)
/ #
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. It makes more sense  on what i was trying to achieve now